# Android service called periodically by the system?

Tags: android, service, battery

I have a background service that is active at certain times - such as when a call comes in.  While working to optimize battery use I noticed that its onStartCommand() is being called every 10 minutes.  I wasn't doing that, so I looked...

```
08-11 10:54:25.938: VERBOSE/com.dcd.monitor.MonitorService(32194): onStartCommand() on thread MonitorService(1)
08-11 10:54:25.938: WARN/System.err(32194): java.lang.Throwable
08-11 10:54:25.938: WARN/System.err(32194):     at com.dcd.monitor.MonitorService.onStartCommand(MonitorService.java:83)
08-11 10:54:25.938: WARN/System.err(32194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
08-11 10:54:25.938: WARN/System.err(32194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-11 10:54:25.938: WARN/System.err(32194):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
08-11 10:54:25.938: WARN/System.err(32194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 10:54:25.948: WARN/System.err(32194):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-11 10:54:25.948: WARN/System.err(32194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-11 10:54:25.948: WARN/System.err(32194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 10:54:25.948: WARN/System.err(32194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-11 10:54:25.948: WARN/System.err(32194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-11 10:54:25.958: WARN/System.err(32194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-11 10:54:25.958: WARN/System.err(32194):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now why might that happen?  (it does have a partial wakelock on it). 
hmm something tells me this is staring me in the face but I'm not getting it.

Seems to me I recall reading that it's inefficient to start stuff unless needed :)

Thanks..

Comment: Look at the Intent passed to `onStartCommand()` and see if it rings any bells.

Comment: The Intent shows a launchFlag = 4 ("background") and extra.ALARM_COUNT = 1.

It sure looks like an alarm, but I patched out the two sources of alarms in my code and it is still being invoked.  The service does not specify any intent filters, and I've looked at explicit invocations.  Weeerd...